# Calculate Gross Private Product from standard metrics

Tags: economic-measurement

Is it possible to calculate GPP given commonly available data like GDP and government expenditure? The example in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_product_remaining) seems to suggest those two alone are enough. Would nominal GDP minus federal spending equal GPP? Do I have to account for state spending too and is there any source for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract G from GDP, but I would advise that you use the same data that were used to construct GDP since different datasets might collect data with different methodology or have different definitions of variables.

Datasets that provide GDP will almost always provide also components of GDP, for example see [Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=National_accounts_-_main_GDP_aggregates_and_related_indicators#Further_analysis_of_main_GDP_aggregates).

Answer (score -1):

Use Nominal GDP minus [Government Consumption Expenditures and Gross Investment](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GCE)

Source: https://www.doe.k12.de.us/cms/lib/DE01922744/Centricity/domain/66/performance%20tasks/GDP%20and%20Happiness%20gr%2010%20FINAL.docx